# Getting List of Members for DL's from .csv/.txt

Tags: exchange, powershell, exchange-2010

I've been tasked with getting a list of all members for a list of 500+ distribution lists (DLs).  I currently have the list (of DLs) in an excel/csv that basically lists the names and primary smtp addresses of the DL's I need to get the members for.

My question is, is there a way using Exchange Shell to get the members of each DL listed and then output to a new (single) file with all of the DL's and the members per each DL?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A very basic example:

```
$lines = get-content groupList.txt

foreach ($line in $lines)
{
add-content -path memberList.txt "Group: $line"
$members = get-adgroupmember $line
foreach ($member in $members)
{ add-content -path memberList.txt "$member" }
}
```